# Detect device from webserver

Tags: proxy, webserver, device, detection

we are currently working on device detection for our subscription. Problem is easy but complicated to solve.

**Problem we have**

Want to have premium subscription which allows you to read our published content on maximum of three devices. These devices can be smartphones, tablets, computers.

**What we tried**

User-Agent parsing - problem of this method is simple, if you have ONE device, you can use multiple browsers (still on one device), and UA is changing - so in the end, we thought that our customers are using more than one device.

Another problem was that UA contains minor versions of browsers and OS, so when somebody updated for example Chrome, we detect that it's new device.

**Data we have in moment of authorisation**

We have proxy written in LUA which is Varnish module for checking if user is logged, if have subscription and how many devices this user is using.

So we are checking device on Varnish level (which is cache level) - first level. In this case we have informations about request, cookies, ip address, user-agent...

We have a little problem with algorithm which should improve our detection. There are many possibilities but we didn't find any suitable for us.

Suggestions?

**Cases which are problematic**

- When somebody update browser - problem with UA solution
- When somebody leave wi-fi or have dynamic IP address - IP address detection problem
- Set cookie - Browser related problem
- When somebody want to show
  desktop version of our mobile website - UA is changed

Suggestions?